# React Checkbox Component returns unique key prop error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react checkbox reusable component that returns the unique key prop error and checks all the boxes in the values array when anyone is clicked.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Checkboxes({name, values}) {
    // handle with dispatch from globalState
    const useCheckbox = () => {
        const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

        return {
            checked,
            onChange: e => setChecked(e.target.checked)
        }
    }

    const checkbox = useCheckbox()

    return (
        <>
            {
                values.map((value, key) => (
                    <>
                        <input key={`${name}-${key}`} type="checkbox" value={value} {...checkbox} /> {value}
                    </>
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

It's used heavily within the application to build a questionnaire. An example use case would be

```
<Checkboxes 
    name="Risk_Response_management"
    values={["Program", "Design", "Procurement(Bid/Cost Estimation)", "Production"]} 
/>
```

When any of the values rendered is clicked, all the checkboxes are selected when only one should be selected. The final use case which is described in the comment just above the useCheckbox declaration is to use dispatch from useReducer hooked to a state which should work after the bug is squished to give the current user some visual feedback as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, I'd suggest just using the value for you key, it's a little simpler/cleaner. And you can't use the shorthand fragment syntax because the key needs to be on the top level of what is returned.

Then as to all the checkboxes being selected it is because you only call useCheckbox once and use it for all the checkboxes. Instead, do this.

```
const Checkbox = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={e => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
      />
      {value}
    </>
  );
}

export default function Checkboxes({name, values}) {
    // handle with dispatch from globalState
  return (
    <>
      <p>{name}</p>
      {values.map(value => (
        <Checkbox key={value} value={value} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

[image: Edit sparkling-sun-k50dr]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because you are returning a [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) in your `.map()`, and `key`'s MUST be on the parent element. It should look more like this:

```js
return values.map((value, key) => (
    <span key={`${name}-${key}`}>
        <input type="checkbox" value={value} {...checkbox} /> {value}
    </span>
));
```

Or, you can update how you are creating your fragment, and use [Keyed Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-fragment.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. Learnt that keys should be placed in the parent component

Answer (score 0):

See sandbox for working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-sound-d1v47?file=/src/Checkboxes.js

Notes:

- your state is scoped within your handler function, when it should be scoped in your component
- state should store the value of the checked checkbox
- each checkbox should be conditionally checked against the value in state
- you shouldn't use the index iteration in your keys or map with a fragment as the outer layer

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Checkboxes({ name, values }) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    setChecked(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {values.map(value => (
        <span key={`${name}-${value}`}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            checked={checked === value}
          />{" "}
          {value}
        </span>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. However, I found that this solution gave me a radio button sort of functionality and that's not what's needed at the time

Comment: Also, your code sandbox is broken so I couldn't see it in action. Thanks for the notes however, really informative